# Theano error when using PyMC3: theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError

Tags: python-3.x, theano, pymc3

I am generating some (noisy) data-points (y) with some known parameters (m,c) that represent the equation of a straight line. Using sampling-based Bayesian methods, I now want to know the true values of parameters (m,c) from the data. Therefore, I am using DE Metropolis (PyMC3) to estimate the true parameters.

I am getting theano error `theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: Input 0 of the graph (indices start from 0), used to compute sigmoid(c_interval__), was not provided and not given a value.`

Theano version: 1.0.4

PyMC3 version: 3.9.1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import arviz as az
import pymc3
import theano.tensor as tt
from theano.compile.ops import as_op

plt.style.use("ggplot")

# define a theano Op for our likelihood function
class LogLike(tt.Op):
    itypes = [tt.dvector] # expects a vector of parameter values when called
    otypes = [tt.dscalar] # outputs a single scalar value (the log likelihood)

    def __init__(self, loglike, data, x, sigma):
        # add inputs as class attributes
        self.likelihood = loglike
        self.data = data
        self.x = x
        self.sigma = sigma

    def perform(self, node, inputs, outputs):
        # the method that is used when calling the Op
        theta, = inputs  # this will contain my variables

        # call the log-likelihood function
        logl = self.likelihood(theta, self.x, self.data, self.sigma)

        outputs[0][0] = np.array(logl) # output the log-likelihood


def my_model(theta, x):
    y = theta[0]*x + theta[1]
    return y

def my_loglike(theta, x, data, sigma):
    model = my_model(theta, x)
    ll = -(0.5/sigma**2)*np.sum((data - model)**2)
    return ll


# set up our data
N = 10  # number of data points
sigma = 1.  # standard deviation of noise
x = np.linspace(0., 9., N)

mtrue = 0.4  # true gradient
ctrue = 3.   # true y-intercept

truemodel = my_model([mtrue, ctrue], x)

# make data
np.random.seed(716742)  # set random seed, so the data is reproducible each time
data = sigma*np.random.randn(N) + truemodel
print(data)

ndraws = 3000  # number of draws from the distribution

# create our Op
logl = LogLike(my_loglike, data, x, sigma)

# use PyMC3 to sampler from log-likelihood
with pymc3.Model():
    # uniform priors on m and c
    m = pymc3.Uniform('m', lower=-10., upper=10.)
    c = pymc3.Uniform('c', lower=-10., upper=10.)

    # convert m and c to a tensor vector
    theta = tt.as_tensor_variable([m, c])

    # use a DensityDist (use a lamdba function to "call" the Op)
    pymc3.DensityDist('likelihood', lambda v: logl(v), observed={'v': theta})

    step = pymc3.DEMetropolis()
    trace = pymc3.sample(ndraws, step)

# plot the traces
axes = az.plot_trace(trace)
fig = axes.ravel()[0].figure
fig.savefig('./trace_plots.png')
```

Find the full trace here:

```
Population sampling (4 chains)
DEMetropolis: [c, m]
Attempting to parallelize chains to all cores. You can turn this off with `pm.sample(cores=1)`.
Population parallelization failed. Falling back to sequential stepping of chains.---------------------| 0.00% [0/4 00:00<00:00]
Sampling 4 chains for 0 tune and 4_000 draw iterations (0 + 16_000 draws total) took 5 seconds.███████| 100.00% [4000/4000 00:04<00:00]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 75, in <module>
    trace = pymc3.sample(ndraws, step)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.py", line 599, in sample
    idata = arviz.from_pymc3(trace, **ikwargs)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arviz/data/io_pymc3.py", line 531, in from_pymc3
    save_warmup=save_warmup,
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arviz/data/io_pymc3.py", line 159, in __init__
    self.observations, self.multi_observations = self.find_observations()
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arviz/data/io_pymc3.py", line 172, in find_observations
    multi_observations[key] = val.eval() if hasattr(val, "eval") else val
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/graph.py", line 522, in eval
    self._fn_cache[inputs] = theano.function(inputs, self)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 317, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 486, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1839, in orig_function
    name=name)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1487, in __init__
    accept_inplace)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 181, in std_fgraph
    update_mapping=update_mapping)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/fg.py", line 175, in __init__
    self.__import_r__(output, reason="init")
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/fg.py", line 346, in __import_r__
    self.__import__(variable.owner, reason=reason)
  File "/home/csl_user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/fg.py", line 391, in __import__
    raise MissingInputError(error_msg, variable=r)
theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: Input 0 of the graph (indices start from 0), used to compute sigmoid(c_interval__), was not provided and not given a value. Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high', for more information on this error.
```

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same problem when following the example how to sample from a black box likelihood found here:
https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/blackbox_external_likelihood.html

This seems to be a version problem. I'm on Manjaro Linux and also ran theano 1.0.4 and pymc3 3.9 using python 3.8. I could solve the issue and make the code work by downgrading to python 3.7 and pymc3 3.8. This seems to be in issue with python 3.8, as simply downgrading pymc3 did not solve the issue for me. I am far from an expert in pymc3 so I don't have a solution how to fix this issue using the newest versions, but for now downgrading makes my simulations run.

Hope this helps.

Edit: The devs seem to be aware of this, there is a an open issue on their github page

https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/4002

Comment: Thanks @SarahS, I am using Python3.7. I will downgrade the PyMC3 version and check.